# absolute asymptotic condition number uniqueness differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, stability-in-odes, continuity, condition-number

Suppose that we have a piecewise, differential equation. Say

$\frac{dx}{dt} = \begin{cases} x \sin \frac{1}{x} & x \neq 0 \\ 0 & x = 0\end{cases}$

$x(0) = 0$

I like to ask if the differential equation has a unique solution. I have tried two different methods, but none of them can seem to tell me anything. Later, a friend told me about his theorem, but I am unsure if his theorem is true or not.

**Theorem 1 Lipschitz**

$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq L |x - y|$,

It doesn't seem to satisfy the Lipschitz condition when $x^{-1} = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2 n \pi$ and $y^{-1} = \frac{3\pi}{2} + 2 n \pi$ because I end up getting $L$ to be $2(2n+1)$ and when $n \to \infty$, $L \to \infty$. So I don't think I can apply the theorem because it doesn't fit the first part of the theorem.

**Theorem 2 Continuity**

If $f(t,y)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are continuous functions in some rectangle $α<t<β$, $γ<y<δ$ containing the point $(t_o,y_o)$, then there is a unique solution to the IVP in some interval $t_o – h < t < t_o+h$ that is contained in $α<t<β$.

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is not continuous so I don't think I can apply the theorem because it also doesn't fit the first part of the theorem.

**Theorem 3 Absolute Asymptotic Condition Number** (unsure of this theorem)

If $f(x)$ has a constant as an absolute asymptotic condition number, then the differential equation has a unique solution. It seems to be saying that if

$\underset{x \to 0}{\lim} \sup \frac{|f(x) - f(0)|}{|x - 0|} < \infty$

then it has a unique solution.

I calculated the absolute asymptotic condition number to be 1, which is a constant. I believe that it is also saying that it is asymptotically stable. Furthermore, since it satisfies the theorem, then I must say the differential equation has a unique solution.

So does this differential equation actually have a unique solution?

If I am wrong saying that, since I can't use the first part of the theorem, I cannot use the theorem, then let me know.

Please and thank you.

Comment: Is it $y'(x)=f(x)$ or $y'(x)=f(y(x))$? In the first case you are really asking about the integral $\int_0^x f(s)\,ds$ which exists as Riemann integral as this $f$ is continuous everywhere.

Comment: Oh sorry, thanks for noticing that. Yea I meant y' = f(y). I will see if I can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x(0)\in \left[\frac1{(n+1)\pi},\frac1{n\pi}\right]$ then go some step below, set $a=\frac1{2n\pi}$ and recognize that on $x\in[a,\infty)$ the right side is smooth, so the existence and uniqueness theorem applies.

But as $x_L(t)=\frac1{(n+1)\pi}$ and $x_U(t)=\frac1{n\pi}$ are constant solutions, they bound the solution $x(t)$ which thus exists for all times.

By exclusion, the solution $x(t)=0$ is also unique, no branching to non-zero values is possible.

---

Your counter-example for the Lipschitz condition is not correctly constructed, you probably wanted $x^{-1} = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2 n \pi$ and $y^{-1} = \frac{3\pi}{2} + 2 n \pi$ so that the sine factor has values $\pm 1$. But then
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|=x+y=\frac{2\pi+4n\pi}{(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2 n\pi)(\frac{3\pi}{2} + 2 n\pi)}\sim\frac1n
$$
which is still asymptotically larger than 
$$x-y=\frac{\pi}{(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2 n\pi)(\frac{3\pi}{2} + 2 n\pi)}\sim\frac1{n^2},$$
so that no Lipschitz constant exists at $x=0$.

Comment: So are you saying that the piecewise differential equation has a unique solution and that solution is x(t) = 0? Which existence and uniqueness theorem are you applying? Is this just the same as the continuity theorem?

Comment: I'm referring to the standard Picard-Lindelöf theorem with extensions towards maximal solutions. The main point is that you have a sequence of roots of $f$ clustered around $x=0$, and each root generates a constant solution that acts as barrier for any other solution.

Comment: Oh ok then. It sounds like you can have more than one solution then, but you can only have one solution per root?

Comment: In principle yes, but you can not cross any of the constant solutions $x(t)=\pm\frac1{n\pi}$, which I mean with the "exclusion" idea.